# Improper integral with singular integrand in three dimensions

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Given the following expression

$$ I(a) = \lim_{\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^3} \, \int_\Omega \nabla \left( \frac{1}{|x-a|} - \frac{1}{|x|} \right) dV $$

where $x$ and $a$ denote vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, I need to evaluate $I(a)$ – or understand where the evaluation fails.

Comment: What does $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^3$ mean?

Comment: It's a finite volume, but in the end I am interested in the integral over the entire $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to replace $\Omega$ with a ball of radius $R$ around $a$, and then let $R \to\infty$?

Comment: Yes. Would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should note that evaluating the expression $I(a)$ fails for $x=0$ and $x=a$. This can be easily seen using the definition of the euclidean norm $|\cdot|$. Suppose $x=0$, then $|x|=\sqrt{0^2+0^2+0^2}=0$, and thus, $\frac{1}{|x|}=\frac{1}{0}$ wich is undefined. Something similar occurs for the norm of $|x-a|$ when $x=a$.

As for the actual value of the improper integral, you should note that for any vector $p\in\mathbb{R}^3$, you will have:
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{|p|}=\infty$$
So, even if you integrate without the singularity vector points, the improper integral $I(a)$ might equate to an undetermined form $\infty-\infty$. Also there is the special case I(0)=0.

Comment: I know that but I think it does not help us here. Please note the difference in brackets and the nabla. By handwaving arguments you could use the principle value around the singularity, which means that this portion of the integral vanishes identically.

Comment: Ah yes. You're right. While it may not blow to infinity it will definitely lead to an undefined form $\infty-\infty$. I'll edit to include this. You might be interested in the special case where $a=0$, wich makes the integral equally zero, but you'll definitely have to exclude the singularities for this to work.